# RewriteCond blank domain to the domain with the correct path

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, iirf

How do I set redirects with following conditions:

Url `http://domainname.be` becomes `http://www.domainname.be/nl/`

Url `http://www.domainname.be` becomes `http://www.domainname.be/nl/`

Url `http://domainname.be/nl/custompage/` becomes `http://www.domainname.be/nl/custompage/`

?

**Rewrite conditions**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainname.be [NC]
RedirectRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainname.be$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainname.be [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RedirectRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainname.be/nl$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainname.be [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RedirectRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainname.be/nl$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/nl/custompage /Custompage.aspx?lang=nl [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/nl/custompage/ /Custompage.aspx?lang=nl [L,NC]
```

But is doesn't work. Also, do you need to clear the browsercache in order to have the latest conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Remove all of your existing rules and use this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainname\.be$ [NC]
RedirectRule ^((?!nl/).*)$ http://www.domainname.be/nl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And yes test it out in a different browser to avoid 301 caching issues.

Comment: it doesn't do anything now. Url `domainname.be` stays the same, also for url with `www`.

Comment: Make sure this rule is very first rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: still the same. I have added some more conditions in my question that I also use maybe it can help

Comment: Look at the latest edit. Make sure you have **no other rule** except this one and test from a different browser.

Comment: now I get this: http://www.domainname.be/nl//nl//nl//nl//nl//nl//nl//nl//nl//nl//nl//nl//nl//nl//nl//nl//nl//nl//nl//nl//

Comment: still the same, it even doesn't show my webpage anymore

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any other rewrite rule anywhere including in `/nl/` directory? What is happening when you enter `http://domain.com/` in your browser?